# Can't get rid of a column while writing data to a csv file using reverse search

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to read different id numbers from a csv file in order to use them with a link to populate result and write the result in a different csv file.

This is the base link `https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?abn=` and these are the numbers (stored in a csv file) `78007306283`,`70007746536`,`95051096649` appended to that link to make them usable links. Those numbers are under `ids` header in the csv file. One such qualified link is `https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?abn=78007306283`.

My script can read the numbers from a csv file, append them one by one in that link, populate the result in the website and write them in another csv file after extraction.

The only problem I'm facing is that my newly created csv file contains the `ids` header as well whereas I would like to exclude that column in the new csv file.

***How can I get rid of a column available in the old csv file when writing the result in a new csv file?***

I've tried so far:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?abn={}"

with open("itemids.csv", "r") as f, open('information.csv', 'w', newline='') as g:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    newfieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['Name', 'Status']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, fieldnames=newfieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for entry in reader:
        res = requests.get(URL.format(entry['ids']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        item = soup.select_one("span[itemprop='legalName']").text
        stat = soup.find("th",string="ABN status:").find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)

        print(item,stat)

        new_row = entry
        new_row['Name'] = item
        new_row['Status'] = stat
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is basically pointing out that the use of pandas can give some control over manipulating tables (Ie, you want to get get rid of a column). You certainly can do it using csv and BeautifulSoup, but in less line of code, the same is accomplished with pandas.

For example, just using your list of the 3 ids, could generate a table to easily write to file:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

URL = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?abn="

# Read in your csv with the ids
id_df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')

#create your list of ids from that csv
id_list = list(id_df['ids'])

results = pd.DataFrame()
for entry in id_list:
    url = URL+'%s' %(str(entry))
    res = requests.get(url)

    table = pd.read_html(url)[0]

    name = table.iloc[0,1]
    status = table.iloc[1,1]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[name,status]], columns = ['Name', 'Status'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv('path/new_file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
                                           name                   status
0  AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL MEMORIAL THEATRE LIMITED  Active from 30 Mar 2000
1                MCDONNELL INDUSTRIES PTY. LTD.  Active from 24 Mar 2000
2                         FERNSPOT PTY. LIMITED  Active from 01 Nov 1999
3                         FERNSPOT PTY. LIMITED  Active from 01 Nov 1999
```

As far as with the code you're dealing with, I believe the issue is with:

```
new_row = entry
```

because `entry` refers to file f, which has that `id` column. What you could do is drop the column right before you write. And technically, I believe it's a dictionary you have, so you just need to delete whatever that key:value is:

I don't have a way to test at the moment, but I'm thinking it would be something like:

```
    new_row = entry
    new_row['Name'] = item
    new_row['Status'] = stat
    del new_row ['id'] #or whatever the key is for that id value

    writer.writerow(new_row)
```

**EDIT / ADDITIONAL**

The reason it's still showing is because of this line:

```
newfieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['Name', 'Status']
```

Since you have `reader = csv.DictReader(f)`, it's including the `ids` column. So in your `newfieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['Name', 'Status']`, you're including the field names from the original csv. Just drop the `reader.fieldnames +`, and initialize your `new_row = {}`

I think this should work it out:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?abn={}"

with open("itemids.csv", "r") as f, open('information.csv', 'w', newline='') as g:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    newfieldnames = ['Name', 'Status']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, fieldnames=newfieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for entry in reader:
        res = requests.get(URL.format(entry['ids']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        item = soup.select_one("span[itemprop='legalName']").text
        stat = soup.find("th",string="ABN status:").find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)

        print(item,stat)

        new_row = {}
        new_row['Name'] = item
        new_row['Status'] = stat
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @chitown88. The thing is when I use `del new_row['ids']` just before write command, It does kick out the values but the column is still there. I wanted to get rid of that column entirely.

Comment: hmmm. ok. I'll take another look at it in a minute.

Comment: I think I found the issue. Give me a second and I'll add it to the solution above

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't want to get rid of that coulmn from old csv;rather, I wanted that column not to include in the new csv file. Thanks.

Comment: ok. ya just went back and re-read the question. I see what you mean. That's how I interpreted it initially. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do web scraping in Python using Pandas package too. Less code you know. You can get a data frame first  and then you'll select any column  or row. Take a look at how I did https://medium.com/@alcarsil/python-for-cryptocurrencies-absolutely-beginners-how-to-find-penny-cryptos-and-small-caps-72de2eb6deaa

Comment: I really don't understand how can this be an answer to my very specific question @Alessandro Carvalho. I didn't even add the `pandas` tag either. Thanks.